# How to access system shutdown with a shortcut in Freya?

Tags: release-freya, keyboard-shortcuts

How to create a shortcut that would bring the restart-shutdown menu?

Comment: I don't know the command - I just screenshotted the shut down menu when I click turn off.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just researching it atm

Comment: That's fine :-)

Comment: @Tim - as I don't mind posting childish questions: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/368/170

Comment: It's not childish - I posted it on Ask Ubuntu today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This worked in Freya but doesn't work in Loki.**

---

Go to System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom.

Add new command by clicking the <kbd>+</kbd> button and add: `gnome-session-quit --power-off`, then press keys to create shortcut.

Log out and in to be able to use the new shortcut.

[image]

I think it looks even more elementary OS-style than the default shutdown menu.

The command for the default shutdown menu is (as provided by [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/559/170)):

```
dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=com.canonical.Unity /org/gnome/SessionManager/EndSessionDialog org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog.Open uint32:2 uint32:0 uint32:0 array:objpath:[]
```

[image]

Comment: this was valid for Freya, doesn't work in Loki