# What is the command behind the default shutdown menu in Freya?

Tags: release-freya, command-line, shutdown

I can access two different shutdown menus.

One is the default one :

[image: Default elementary shutdown menu]

The other is the one triggered by the command `gnome-session-quit --power-off` :

[image: gnome-session-quit --power-off - shutdown menu]

When looking for a command that I could use with a shortcut to shut down the system, this is the one I could find.

I'm curious what is the command for the default menu :)

Comment: I am just guessing, see if this works
"
sudo shutdown -h now
"

Comment: @jaga - The shutdown menu does not need `sudo`, while `shutdown -h now `cannot be used without `sudo`.

Comment: yup that is true

Comment: I'm told it's triggered through a `dbus-send` command, but we can't seem to find a reference in it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can launch the shutdown menu with the following command

```
dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=com.canonical.Unity /org/gnome/SessionManager/EndSessionDialog org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog.Open uint32:2 uint32:0 uint32:0 array:objpath:[]
```

Comment: Wow. Simply wow. Great job! Removed my answer to avoid shame :)

Comment: Should this work in Loki? It seems  [that it doesn't](https://plus.google.com/+CipricusCipriq/posts/JJZU8rJa4xM).