# What is the command for the shutdown dialogue in Loki?

Tags: release-loki, command-line, shutdown

I asked the same [question for Freya](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/368/170) but in Loki the situation is different, none of the two dialogues can be triggered with those commands.

`gnome-session-quit --power-off` used to trigger this dialogue:

[image]

while the default dialogue was triggered by the command `dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=com.canonical.Unity /org/gnome/SessionManager/EndSessionDialog org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog.Open uint32:2 uint32:0 uint32:0 array:objpath:[]`.

[image]

Asking on the g+ group [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/368/170), the command `dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=/org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.power_off` was mentioned, but it doesn't work.

What is the command behind the default Loki Shutdown dialogue? I prefer to use a shortcut for that, especially that the shutdown laptop button triggers no dialogue but suspends directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not quite what you wanted, but here was what I was able to find:

Shutdown directly:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.PowerOff" boolean:true
```

Reboot directly:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Reboot" boolean:true
```

Sleep directly:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend" boolean:true
```

<sup>[Theses commands](http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=16497311#p16497311) will immediately trigger the action without any confirmation dialogue — it's the hook that the dialog box uses.</sup>

The dialog box you're after is known as **EndSessionDialog**. It's part of [Wingpanel's session indicator](https://launchpad.net/wingpanel-indicator-session). [Here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~wingpanel-devs/wingpanel-indicator-session/trunk/view/head:/src/Widgets/EndSessionDialog.vala) is where it's built. [Here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~wingpanel-devs/wingpanel-indicator-session/trunk/view/head:/src/Indicator.vala) is where the indicator calls it. [Here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~wingpanel-devs/wingpanel-indicator-session/trunk/view/head:/src/Services/DbusInterfaces.vala) is where the indicator interfaces with `dbus`. [Here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~wingpanel-devs/wingpanel-indicator-session/trunk/revision/93) is when `org.gnome.SessionManager` was swapped out for `org.freedesktop.login1`.

After much `gdbus introspect`ion, I surmise that it's going to be similar to the original `dbus` command with `/org/gnome/SessionManager` swapped for `/org/freedesktop/login1`, but I don't speak the language well enough to find the hook. But I emailed the maintainer so we'll see what we hear back.

Comment: what about the logout?

Comment: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/login/org.freedesktop.login1.conf

Answer (score 0):

I just had to go through this myself.. and with the info provided by wolf I was able to piece together the rest of it with a little bit of digging and I will answer your question to him in the comments.

Also to note - this is on the latest Hera version, so mileage may vary with Loki given the age of the post.

How to activate that prompt.

```
#!/bin/bash

# run wingpanel if it isn't running already

dbus-send --print-reply --dest="org.gnome.Shell" /org/gnome/SessionManager/EndSessionDialog org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog.Open uint32:2 uint32:0 uint32:60 array:objpath:/org/gnome/SessionManager/EndSessionDialog
```

Note: I am using a different DE - mate. Ideally I should kill wingpanel in like 10 seconds or so if there is no activity

How to logoff directly?

This took a lot of different tries, but finally I came up with this. It is important that both run or you will not log back in well.

```
loginctl kill-session $XDG_SESSION_ID; loginctl terminate-session $XDG_SESSION_ID
```

As a scripted solution though the above logoff code does not work, you will need to use the wingpanel still and the following for the dialog prompt first

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.Logout uint32:1
```